# How to use libstdc++ namespace when using libc++ as standard library?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libstdc++, libc++

**Short Question**
When I set `C++ Standard Library` as `libc++` on Xcode, how can I use `string` of `libstdc++`?

**Background**
I'm in trouble with using two 3rd-party libraries. **Library A** is based on `libc++` and **Library B** is based on `libstdc++`. So, I set `C++ Standard Library` as `libc++` and imported `libstdc++.6.tbd`
Compilation goes okay, however, here is the problem.

```
const std::string param1 = [nsstring1 UTF8String];
LibraryBFunction(3, param1);
```

When `LibraryBFunction` is called, an error occurred.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'LibraryBFunction'
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const string' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') to 'const string' (aka 'const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >') for 2nd argument
```

I think Xcode compiler changes `std` namespace in code to `std::__1` which belongs to `libc++`. So, I want to use `std::string` of `libstdc++`, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: In general it isn't possible to link two different versions of the C++ standard library to an application. Can you recompile either of the 3rd party libraries?

Comment: It's hard part of me. 3rd party library codes are not belong to me. I'm not an expert on C++, but compilation was OK. I had a compile error before importing `libstdc++.6`. I followed [Simeon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642554/1010443).

Comment: Might be of [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794607/mixing-stdc-and-libc-in-an-ios-project).

Comment: @super It solved my problem. Super thank you!